# vimscript create list of files i can jump to (CtrlP or NERDTree or Quickfix?)

Tags: vim, nerdtree, ctrlp

with a vimscript-function, i created an array with list of filepathes.

now i want to open that list in a seperate window, for beeing able to open that files in vim.

it could be like [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) or [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) or via quickfix or location-lists.

Has someone an idea how to start on that?

Comment: Maybe look at the source for CtrlP?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to work with this would be the quickfix window. You can use the list of files with the `setqflist()` function: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#setqflist().

You might have to make some adjustments to the data you feed to the function, but it shouldn't be difficult if you already happen to have a list of files.

If you'd like to make the `NERDTree` show your files, that would be a bit stranger, but you could probably pull it off by using the `NERDTreeAddPathFilter()` function. You can read up on it by invoking `:help NERDTreeAddPathFilter()`. The basic idea would be to introduce a filter function that would only display (in the tree) the files that are included within this list.